# Sending data back and forth from android server to python client

Tags: java, python, android, sockets, server

I have posted this few days back but now i ran into another problem after solving that one.

**DESCRIPTION:** working on an android app written in kotlin that behaves as a server side and Python program that works as a client both runs on same computer and try to send and receive messages from each other.I'm using a text view to display messages that i'm receiving from PC(python).

**Problem:** whenever i try to run client program in python.I get following output on terminal.I don't get the message that server sends on connection

```
server sent something.....
 b''
you are about to.....
```

whereas on the server side it doesn't receives anything from client.

**What i have Tried:** I have used port forwarding which maps port 5000 on client to 6000 on emulator as someone suggested that in the previous post which basically solved my **error:61 connection refused** on client side writen in python but unfortunately i have this problem.Is this because of the fact that i'm using kotlin on server side to communicate with python and should use java instead.
Or i'm using wrong thread logic.

**Please help me out**

```
import socket


def main():
    client_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    client_socket.connect(('127.0.0.1', 5000))
    while True:
        data = client_socket.recv(1024)
        print("server sent something.....\n", data)
        print("you are about to.....")
        client_socket.sendall(bytes("hey server....", 'utf-8'))
        break
    client_socket.close()


main()
```

```
package com.example.soundsource

import android.content.Intent
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.os.Handler
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.TextView
import java.net.ServerSocket
import java.net.Socket
import java.io.*





class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {



    private lateinit var textView:TextView

    companion object{
        const val COMMUNICATIONPORT = 6000
        private lateinit var serversocket:ServerSocket
        private lateinit var serverThread:Thread
        private lateinit var updateConversationHandler:Handler
    }


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
//        val sendButton:Button = findViewById(R.id.send_button)
        val showLocation = findViewById(R.id.show_location) as? Button
        showLocation?.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(this,SoundLocation::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
        }
        textView = findViewById(R.id.text_view)
//        sendButton.setOnClickListener{
//            serverThread = Thread(ServerThread())
//            serverThread.start()
//        }
        serverThread = Thread(ServerThread())
        serverThread.start()
    }

    class ServerThread:Runnable{
        override fun run() {
            var socket: Socket
            try {
                serversocket = ServerSocket(COMMUNICATIONPORT)

            } catch (e:IOException) {
                e.printStackTrace()
            }

            while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted) {

                try {

                    socket = serversocket.accept()
                    val message = "client connected from ${socket.localAddress} and ${socket.localPort}....."
                    MainActivity().textView.text = message
                    val commThread = CommunicationThread(socket)
                    Thread(commThread).start()

                } catch (e: IOException) {
                    e.printStackTrace()
                }

            }
        }
    }


    class CommunicationThread(clientSocket: Socket) : Runnable {

        private var input: BufferedReader? = null
        private var output:PrintWriter? = null

        init {

            try {

                input = BufferedReader(InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()))
                output = PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(),true)

            } catch (e: IOException) {
                e.printStackTrace()
            }

        }

        override fun run() {

            while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted) {

                try {
                    output!!.println("Thanks for connecting with me.....")
                    val read = input!!.readLine()

                    updateConversationHandler.post(MainActivity().UpdateUIThread(read))

                } catch (e: IOException) {
                    e.printStackTrace()
                }

            }
        }

    }

    internal inner class UpdateUIThread(private val msg: String) : Runnable {

        override fun run() {
            val message =  "Client Says: $msg \n"
            textView.text = message
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: `both runs on same computer ` ? You have an Android computer? `android server python client`.

Answer (score 0):

your Android App is listening on Port 6000 and the Python script is talking to 5000. Also sure your Android has IP of localhost ?